# ASP.NET Membership - A design for tracking additional information

Tags: asp.net, database-design, web-applications, asp.net-membership

I'm working on an ASP.NET4.0/C# application for a public site that needs to authenticate only the employees that work at the associated business. The idea is for the site to have a CMS such that employees can go in and make changes to certain content without having to work with any html.

My question relates to the design and use of a ASP.NET membership provider. I'm not trying to make the site work with an existing database, so there's no need to create my own MembershipProvider for that purpose. However, since each user is an employee, I want to track additional information such as name and office number. I can think of two readily apparent ways to accomplish this:

1. Use the default SqlMembershipProvider class. As a result, I would need to add the appropriate tables to my database and create a separate table for any "additional" information I want to store. This effectively creates a vertical partition on the user table, since I would use the asp.net-assigned userID as the primary key of the employee table as well. To retrieve the "additional" information, I could ask the provider for information about the current user and requery the database in the event I want to know anything else.
2. Create one table for all employee information (including login and password) and create my own custom MembershipProvider and MembershipUser classes with the functionality I desire.

I've also considered the use of profiles to store such information, however, the site will publicly contain employee listings, and these pages will need to access some of this information. As a result, I should probably cache this data and it seems like using the serialized fields that profiles provide would cause a problem.

Thus, purely in regards to design... would it be best to make a distinction between a user and an employee and use the default SqlMembershipProvider and associated tables, or write my own user tables that store the information I need and my own MembershipProvider for accessing that information?

Comment: Don't you want to use their AD for authentication, office number etc.?

Comment: Yeah, if I was using Windows Authentication. Their work computers aren't necessarily on the same network though, so Forms Authentication would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to store additional user info within the ASP.NET Membership. I've created a number of sites using the following setup.

1. Install the default .NET Membership using the aspnet_regsql.exe tool
2. Create a UserProfile table with a uniqueidentifier (PK) UserID column that is linked via a foreign key to the aspnet_Users table
3. To access that information, all you need is the UserId of a particular User, then you can query your custom table for more information.

Microsoft has written an [excellent post](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) on how to do this.

**Good luck!**

**M**

Comment: Thanks, M. It looks like the general consensus is option 1, and that post is a good reference when implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar, using your option 1. Works great for me.

My business logic has some functions for mutating users. It knows when to touch my users table or the Membership functionality.

Using a custom MembershipProvider for this sort of thing will give you more work than you bargained for.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Table profile provider (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/10/435038.aspx ) will help you do just that.
You will get the power of the Profiles and on the same time not worry about caching or serialization since this provider stores the profile information in clear database table without any serialization. You can use them directly in your queries.